# Words missing from trained word2vec model vocabulary

Tags: python, tensorflow, nltk, gensim, word2vec

I am currently working with python where I train a Word2Vec model using sentences that I provide. Then, I save and load the model to get the word embedding of each and every word in the sentences that were used to train the model. However, I get the following error.

> KeyError: "word 'n1985_chicago_bears' not in vocabulary"

whereas, one of the sentences provided during training is as follows.

```
sportsteam n1985_chicago_bears teamplaysincity city chicago
```

Hence I would like to know why some words are missing from the vocabulary, despite being trained on those words from that sentence corpus.

**Training the word2vec model on own corpus**

```
import nltk
import numpy as np
from termcolor import colored
from gensim.models import Word2Vec
from gensim.models import KeyedVectors
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA


#PREPARING DATA

fname = '../data/sentences.txt'

with open(fname) as f:
    content = f.readlines()

# remove whitespace characters like `\n` at the end of each line
content = [x.strip() for x in content]


#TOKENIZING SENTENCES

sentences = []

for x in content:
    nltk_tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(x)
    sentences.append(nltk_tokens)

#TRAINING THE WORD2VEC MODEL

model = Word2Vec(sentences)

words = list(model.wv.vocab)
model.wv.save_word2vec_format('model.bin')
```

**Sample sentences from sentences.txt**

```
sportsteam hawks teamplaysincity city atlanta
stadiumoreventvenue honda_center stadiumlocatedincity city anaheim
sportsteam ducks teamplaysincity city anaheim
sportsteam n1985_chicago_bears teamplaysincity city chicago
stadiumoreventvenue philips_arena stadiumlocatedincity city atlanta
stadiumoreventvenue united_center stadiumlocatedincity city chicago
...
```

There are 1860 such lines in the `sentences.txt` file, each containing exactly 5 words and no stop words.

After saving the model, I tried to load it from a different python file within the same directory as the saved `model.bin` as shown below.

**Loading the saved model.bin**

```
import nltk
import numpy as np
from gensim import models

w = models.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('model.bin', binary=True)
print(w['n1985_chicago_bears'])
```

However, I end up with the following error

```
KeyError: "word 'n1985_chicago_bears' not in vocabulary"
```

Is there a way to get the word embedding for each and every word in the trained sentence corpus using the same method?

Any suggestions in this regard will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default `min_count=5` for Word2Vec implementation of gensim and looks like the token you are looking for `n1985_chicago_bears` occurs less then 5 times in your corpus. Change your min count appropriately.

[Method signature:](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html)

> class gensim.models.word2vec.Word2Vec(sentences=None,
>   corpus_file=None, size=100, alpha=0.025, window=5, min_count=5,
>   max_vocab_size=None, sample=0.001, seed=1, workers=3,
>   min_alpha=0.0001, sg=0, hs=0, negative=5, ns_exponent=0.75,
>   cbow_mean=1, hashfxn=, iter=5, null_word=0,
>   trim_rule=None, sorted_vocab=1, batch_words=10000, compute_loss=False,
>   callbacks=(), max_final_vocab=None)

```
content = [
    "sportsteam hawks teamplaysincity city atlanta",
    "stadiumoreventvenue honda_center stadiumlocatedincity city anaheim",
    "sportsteam ducks teamplaysincity city anaheim",
    "sportsteam n1985_chicago_bears teamplaysincity city chicago",
    "stadiumoreventvenue philips_arena stadiumlocatedincity city atlanta",
    "stadiumoreventvenue united_center stadiumlocatedincity city chicago"
]

sentences = []

for x in content:
    nltk_tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(x)
    sentences.append(nltk_tokens)

model = Word2Vec(sentences, min_count=1)
print (model['n1985_chicago_bears'])
```

Comment: Note, though, that the `min_count=5` exists for good reason: rarely occurring words tend not to get very good word-vectors from their few training examples, and further given typical word-distributions (where there are many such 'long tail' few-occurrence words) there can be a lot of such words, which if retained tend to make the word-vectors for *other* words worse. With too few and insufficiently varied examples, they're essentially "noise". So at least in usual natural-language corpuses, discarding rare words improves word2vec-derived results for the more important words.

Comment: Thanks. This worked like magic and since I am currently trying to get a basic system working, I am getting the embeddings for all the terms (even those that occur at least once). But I will be tuning this to make such terms' embedding vectors more meaningful. Thanks once again.

Comment: As @gojomo mentioned it is not recommended to make `min_count=1`. One way to deal with this problem is to replace all very low frequency words with 'UNK' and use the vector representation of UNK for missing words.